# MYSQL GET ALL PRODUCT FROM PARENT CATEGORY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I HAVE TABLE

```
TABLE CATEGORY
id | name | parent
1 | gadget | 0
2 | phone | 1
3 | laptop | 1
....

TABLE PRODUCT
id | name | cat
1 | post 1 | 2
2 | post 2 | 2
3 | post 3 | 3
....
```

i want to get product by category and subcategory

Display all product in gadget category

How i can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just one level of parent/child relationship (as shown in your sample data), you can self-join the `category` table:

```
select p.*, c.name, c1.name
from product p
inner join category c on c.id = p.cat
left join category c1 on c1.id = c.parent
```

Comment: How about if i just have the value of category name only.

Comment: @wayanwahyuAdiPutra: if you want only the products in the `'gadget'` category, you can add a `where` clause at the end of the query: `where c.name = 'gadget' or c1.name = 'gadget'`

Comment: I want all product from category and subcategory. Is that way same?

Comment: @wayanwahyuAdiPutra: this where clause gives you products whose category or subcategory is `'gadget'`.

Answer (score 0):

the simple way, use double query

```
SELECT A.* FROM PRODUCT A
INNER JOIN CATEGORY B ON A.CAT = B.ID
WHERE B.ID = (SELECT ID FROM CATEGORY WHERE NAME = 'gadget') 
OR B.PARENT= (SELECT ID FROM CATEGORY WHERE NAME = 'gadget')
```

Comment: In case i just have value of category name only. Like 'gadget' what should i do?

Comment: use double query